# Spark/Scala: Impossible to make an RDD to DF conversion

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, case-class, linux-disk-free

I am a new programmer of scala(2.11) and spark (1.6.0) who is trying to convert an RDD to a DF without spark-csv package (for practicing but also because of some technical issues). After reading the starter guide of Spark and all the related posts of stackoverflow, I don't know how to make some methods (4) to work -only one works for me, and I don't know why-:

Every help with any of them will be amazing!

I have a simple table like in a txt file:

```
Jorgito 10 1 Soltero
Juanito 20 2 Casado
Jaimito 30 3 Divociado
```

I code a few preliminars:

```
var RDD_filas = RDD_datos.map(_.split("\t"))
var esquema = new StructType()
.add("Nombre", StringType)
.add("Edad", IntegerType)
.add("Hijos",IntegerType)
.add("EC",StringType)

import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType};
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext

case class X(Nombre: String, Edad: Int, Hijos: Int, EC: String)
```

And, then, I apply all the methods I have seen which doesn't work:

```
var DF_datos = RDD_filas.map({case Array(s0, s1, s2, s3) => X(s0, s1.trim.toInt, s2.trim.toInt, s3)}).toDF("Nombre","Edad","Hijos","EC")
var DF_datos2 = RDD_filas.map(p => X(p(0), p(1).trim.toInt,p(2).trim.toInt,p(3))).toDF("Nombre","Edad","Hijos","EC")
var DF_datos3 = RDD_filas.map(Array(s0, s1, s2, s3) => Array(s0, s1.trim.toInt, s2.trim.toInt, s3)).toDF("Nombre","Edad","Hijos","EC")
var DF_datos4 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(RDD_filas,esquema)
```

The first three methods allows me to create the DF and to print their schemas, but they don't have the header (DF_datos.header() returns the first row) and I have an error if I try DF_datos.show()
The strangest one (for me) is number 4, because it is supposed to be the most "canonical" way.

Only this worked for me:

```
var a = RDD_datos.map(_.split(" ")).take(3)
val rdd = sc.makeRDD(a)
val df = rdd.map {case Array(s0, s1, s2, s3) => X(s0, s1.toInt, s2.toInt, s3)}.toDF()
```

Comment: This is the log of the error when I try the fourth method: 

scala> var DF_datos4 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(RDD_filas4,esquema)
<console>:67: error: overloaded method value createDataFrame with alternatives:
  (data: java.util.List[_],beanClass: Class[_])org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
  (rdd: org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD[_],beanClass: Class[_])org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
  (rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[_],beanClass: Class[_])org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
  (rows: java.util.List[org.apache.spark.sql.Row],schema:   ...

Comment: Are sure your data is tab delimited? It looks like spaces in your screen shot

Comment: I tried both with (" ") and ("\t") and none works

Answer (score 3):

In order to use `sqlContext.createDataFrame` you will need to have an `RDD[Row]` where the types of the entries in your rows correspond to the types in your schema. Thus you will need to convert some entries from `String` to `Int` when appropriate.

Here is an example:

```
scala> val data = sc.textFile("./junk/dat.txt")
data: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = ./junk/dat.txt MapPartitionsRDD[20] at textFile at <console>:28

scala> data.foreach{println}
Jorgito 10 1 Soltero
Juanito 20 2 Casado
Jaimito 30 3 Divociado

scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

var esquema = new StructType()
.add("Nombre", StringType)
.add("Edad", IntegerType)
.add("Hijos",IntegerType)
.add("EC",StringType)

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

esquema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(StructField(Nombre,StringType,true), StructField(Edad,IntegerType,true), StructField(Hijos,IntegerType,true), StructField(EC,StringType,true))

scala> val rowRDD = data.map(l => l.split(" ")).map{case Array(a,b,c,d) => Row(a, b.toInt, c.toInt, d)}
rowRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = MapPartitionsRDD[22] at map at <console>:30

scala> val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rowRDD, esquema)
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [Nombre: string, Edad: int ... 2 more fields]

scala> df.show
+-------+----+-----+---------+
| Nombre|Edad|Hijos|       EC|
+-------+----+-----+---------+
|Jorgito|  10|    1|  Soltero|
|Juanito|  20|    2|   Casado|
|Jaimito|  30|    3|Divociado|
+-------+----+-----+---------+
```

However this is a lot of work so I would recommend that you either a) upgrade to Spark 2.0 and use the built in [`DataFrameReader`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader) `csv` loader
or b) look into [`spark-csv`](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv). In both cases you would simply  set the delimiter to `\s` or `\t` as needed.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your code is clear and has sense for me, but I continue reciving an error when I try to print the df: 
var data = sc.textFile("/user/hdfs/landing/Tabla1.txt")
var esquema = new StructType()
.add("Nombre", StringType)
.add("Edad", IntegerType)
(etc...)
val rowRDD = data.map(l => l.split(" ")).map{case Array(a,b,c,d) => Row(a, b.toInt, c.toInt, d)}
val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rowRDD, esquema)
df.show

Comment: 17/01/05 01:28:26 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 9.0 (TID 9)
scala.MatchError: [Ljava.lang.String;@ff07791 (of class [Ljava.lang.String;)
17/01/05 01:28:26 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 9.0 (TID 9)
scala.MatchError: [Ljava.lang.String;@ff07791 (of class [Ljava.lang.String;)

(long etc)

Comment: Hmm, what is the output of `data.foreach{println}`? How about `rowRDD.foreach{println}`?

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to add column headers to the csv using Struct Type

```scala
val df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, structType)
```

If the csv already contains column headers, you can directly convert it into Data frame.

```scala
val df = spark.read.option("headers",true).csv("/path/to/csv")
```

#### Convert to DataFrame from source file

Now as you have used a [custom delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46349762/1097600).

```scala
val df = spark.read.option("delimiter", " ").csv("/path/to/csv")
```