# Custom delimiter csv reader spark

Tags: csv, apache-spark, pyspark

I would like to read in a file with the following structure with Apache Spark.

```
628344092\t20070220\t200702\t2007\t2007.1370
```

The delimiter is \t. How can I implement this while using spark.read.csv()?

The csv is much too big to use pandas because it takes ages to read this file. Is there some way which works similar to

```
pandas.read_csv(file, sep = '\t')
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Use `spark.read.option("delimiter", "\t").csv(file)` or `sep` instead of `delimiter`.

If it's literally `\t`, not tab special character, use double `\`: `spark.read.option("delimiter", "\\t").csv(file)`

Comment: Is there any website to check the documentation of spark.read or anything else? Thanks for the answer! :)

Comment: CSV supports is a merge of this project: https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv It has some documentation. I'm personally just checking the code :)

Comment: What's the difference between sep and delimiter?

Comment: @aglavina None, both means the same :)

Comment: This changed in Spark now, with the pandas solution at the top also possible?

Answer (score 6):

This works for me and it is much more clear (for me):
As you mentioned, in pandas you would do:

```
df_pandas = pandas.read_csv(file_path, sep = '\t')
```

In spark:

```
df_spark = spark.read.csv(file_path, sep ='\t', header = True)
```

Please note that if the first row of your csv are the column names, you should set header = False, like this:

```
df_spark = spark.read.csv(file_path, sep ='\t', header = False)
```

You can change the separator (sep) to fit your data.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **`SparkSQL`**, you can use the DDL below with the `OPTION` syntax to specify your `delimiter`.

```sql
CREATE TABLE sample_table
USING CSV
OPTIONS ('delimiter'='\t')
AS SELECT ...
```

[SparkSQL Documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-create-table-datasource.html)