# Shifted column when reading csv file in pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, pyspark

I have a csv file stored in gcs, when reading this file some values are being shifted by 2 columns and I don't know why. One example is the following row:

```
202100000264277,01212022,*******2752,00000411042,15314.15,27021421334,D,00000000396,JONES HEALTHCARE GROUP,08036296542,8036296542,,02560,15314.15,425.89,0.00,0.00,110,10522,AMEX CA B2B/WHOLESALE 1 CNP,AEXP,372754*****1007,,01212022,01212022,127647,,,A,001383636306309,27021421359,ACH,CAD,,,,02153222888,90662316,62496,62504,,0000000000027021421359X,0089250008036296542157,45280,USA,01,1,,,Y,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

df:

```
                0        1            2       3         4            5  6   \
0  202100000264277  1212022  *******2752  411042  15314.15  27021421334  D   

    7                       8           9           10  11    12        13  \
0  396  JONES HEALTHCARE GROUP  8036296542  8036296542 NaN  2560  15314.15   

       14   15   16   17     18                           19    20  \
0  425.89  0.0  0.0  110  10522  AMEX CA B2B/WHOLESALE 1 CNP  AEXP   

                21  22       23       24      25  26  27 28             29  \
0  372754*****1007 NaN  1212022  1212022  127647 NaN NaN  A  1383636306309   

            30   31   32  33  34  35          36        37     38     39  40  \
0  27021421359  ACH  CAD NaN NaN NaN  2153222888  90662316  62496  62504 NaN   

                        41                      42     43   44  45  46  47  \
0  0000000000027021421359X  0089250008036296542157  45280  USA   1   1 NaN
```

the value in the column 43 should be in 41, I loaded the csv file as text files and then did a split on ','. What could be the possible reasons?

Comment: Why should `45280` appear in column 41? If I run `echo "<input>"|cut -f40-44 -d',' -` I get `62504,,0000000000027021421359X,0089250008036296542157,45280`. So I would guess that the output you are showing is correct.

Comment: because there is a comma somewhere in the data and I cannot know where because there are no double quotations, the number of columns should be 96 not more than that. I need a method to read the csv data but not comma separated, @werner

Comment: You can configure [another delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46349762/2129801) than a comma, but that won't be helpful in your case. What are the rules to identify a new column, if it's not a comma?